# Function series and uniformly convergence.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have 2 questions that i didn't manage to solve.
$ $

1.Let $(f_n):I \to R $ be a series of functions that converge uniformly to f:$I \to R $ Let g:$R \to R $ be a continuous function.
find an example such that ($g\circ f_n)$ does not converge uniformly.
Im not sure if g's domain must be $R$ , if not i could find an example for that.
So please give an example for the other case - g's Domain is $R$.

2.Let $f_n:[a,\infty) \to R$ be a series of functions that converge uniformly to f:$[a,\infty) \to R $
for each $n\in N$ it holds that $ f_n $ is integrability in $[a,M]$
and $\int_{a}^{\infty} f_n (x) dx$ converge. and  $\int_{a}^{\infty} f (x) dx$
converge.
does $lim\int_{a}^{\infty} f_n (x) = \int_{a}^{\infty} f (x) dx$
I think the answer is no , but having trouble finding an example for that.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (1), let $f_n(x)=x+\frac{1}{n}$ and $f(x)=x$. Then $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$. However, if $g(x)=x^2$ then $$g(f_n(x))=x^2+\frac{2x}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}$$
which does not converge uniformly to $g(f(x))=x^2$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

For (2), you are correct that the answer is no. Let $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}$ if $0\leq x\leq n$ and $f_n(x)=0$ otherwise, and let $f(x)=0$. Then $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$. But if we take $a=0$, then
$$ \int_0^{\infty}f_n(x)\;dx=1 $$
for all $n$, so the integrals don't converge to $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)\;dx=0$.